# Error getting value from 'CheckCertificateRevocationList' on 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler'

Tags: c#, json.net, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I'm getting this on my production server, but not my develop or test machines. I'm having a hard time understanding what is wrong here.

```
Error getting value from 'CheckCertificateRevocationList' on 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler'.  
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)     
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)   
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) 
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) 
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)     
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)     
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
```

The error is from trying to serialize a HttpCall call object from FLURL (https://flurl.io/docs/configuration/#event-handlers)

on app init

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.BeforeCallAsync = HandleFlurlBeforeCallAsync);
```

The code:

```
private async Task HandleFlurlBeforeCallAsync(HttpCall call)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            };

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, new
        {
            call.FlurlRequest.Url,
            call.FlurlRequest.Headers,
            call.Request.Content,
            call.Request.RequestUri,
            call.RequestBody,
            call.HttpStatus,
            call.ErrorResponseBody

        });
                var log= sw.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a **[Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: I've included example code, but it's not repoducible on test. sw.ToString() is what fails

Comment: You won't be able to safely serialize a `HttpCall` to JSON. It contains a couple of things which can't be safely serialized, e.g. `Exception` and `HttpRequestMessage` (what happens if `HttpRequestMessage.Content` is a stream, for example?). In this specific case, it might be because `CheckCertificateRevocationList` is documented as throwing a `PlatformNotSupportedException` on .NET Framework 4.7.1. Only serialize objects which are meant to be serialized - you can't serialize any random old object.

Comment: I'm more interested in why I'm getting a CheckCertificateRevocationList error, than how to serialize it.

Comment: Like I said, my best guess is "*In this specific case, it might be because `CheckCertificateRevocationList` is documented as throwing a `PlatformNotSupportedException` on .NET Framework 4.7.1.*"

Comment: I wrote Flurl, and I can't provide a better answer than @canton7 already did. `HttpCall` simply wasn't designed to be serialized in its entirety. Even if it didn't fail, you'd end up with huge, deeply nested objects in your log that wouldn't be pretty to look at. Maybe create an anonymous object with just the the pieces you need picked out of `HttpCall` and serialize that. I can't speak to `CheckCertificateRevocationList` specifically, which it sounds like you're interested in, so I won't provide an answer.